# Are `return await ...` and `return ...` the same?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider these functions:

```js
function waitASecA() {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  return promise; // <--- don't await, just return
}


async function waitASecB() {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  return await promise; // <--- first await, then return
}
```

As I understand they should be EXACTLY the same. Are there any scenarios when they'd differ in behavior?

Comment: They are functionally equivalent. async/await is just syntactic sugar that makes the code a little easier to read, you do not have to use `.then` to utilize the results of a `Promise`. In the case of the above code though there is no difference.

Comment: Don't forget the third version `async function waitASecC() { …; return promise }` :-)

Comment: You are still going to `await` the response when you call these anyways. Adding `await` inside is pointless.

Comment: yes, that was exactly what I thought, thanks for confirming guys!